# Copy files from a folder name determined by wildcard batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line, wildcard

I am trying to achieve the following with a batch file:

1. Access a shared drive using `net use`: DONE
2. Ask the user for a version number: DONE
3. Use the version number to look for a specific folder: NOT DONE

   ex: user enters *6*, I need to copy all files from a folder that is named as *product_version6_[TIMESTAMP]*.

for the user input I have:

```
set /p versionNumber="Enter Version number : "
```

I have tried using wild cards `product_version%versionNumber%_*` but I get invalid parameter message or does not exist message.

In short, what I am trying to achieve is ask the user for a version number and look for a directory based on that version number.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have an example of such a version number and a couple of directories (one that contains the version entered by the user and other that doesn't). Also, the directories (full path) are on the network drive?

Answer (score 0):

Update: the following solution worked for me

```
for /d %%a in (%SourceDir%\product_version%versionNumber%_*) do xcopy "%%a" "%Destination%" /S /I /Y /K
```